# Apex 22.1 How To Pass JWT To A REST Data Source

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-22

I have added an external OData REST Service as a REST Data Source in my APEX application. Defined a LOV against this REST Data Source and it is being shown as a Popup.

I have another external service which is secured with JWT. How can i pass the token in REST Data Source definition (for example via Web Credential) to have the same above functionality?

For example if i am calling the service from PL/SQL then i would pass JWT as

```
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Authorization';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'Bearer ' || 'my JWT';
RESP_JSON := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST(
    P_URL => URL, 
    P_HTTP_METHOD => 'get'
);
```

Authentication Type: OAuth2 Client Credentials Flow is not required as i don't have Client ID and Secret as well as a specifc endpoint to acquire token.

I have tried this with the REST Data Source, no success

```
No Authentication
Parameters
Name: Authorization
Value: Bearer :GLOB_TOKEN
```

Any Application Item mentioned in Parameters is not resoved because one of the debug message is

> default value for parameter (1) "Authorization" is "Bearer
> :GLOB_TOKEN"

Then what is the purpose of `Static` flag (which is off in my added parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Web Credential of the **HTTP Header** type. Then use **Authorization** as the name (key) and **Bearer {JWT}** as the value. Then simply assign the credential to the REST Source.

You can then use APEX_CREDENTIAL.SET_SESSION_CREDENTIALS or APEX_CREDENTIAL.SET_PERSISTENT_CREDENTIAL to change the token value if required.

The credential will work on the HTTP Header level, and it won’t be aware that this is a JWT; but things should just work.